# Reading in kernel second time overrides first instance

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have written a read function to read a file into buffer in Kernel space.

```
int readfile(const char *filename, void *buf, int len, int offset) 
{
    struct file *filp;
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int bytes;
    filp = NULL;
    filp = filp_open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if(!filp || IS_ERR(filp)) {
        printk(" Error in reading file %s. Error = %d\n", filename, \
               (int) PTR_ERR(filp));
        return -1;
    }
    filp->f_pos = offset;
    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());
    bytes = vfs_read(filp, buf, len, &filp->f_pos);
    set_fs(oldfs);
    filp_close(filp, NULL);
    return bytes;
}
```

Now, this function works really well and I am able to read contents of filename into buf by calling this function from my system call

```
char *firstbuffer;
firstbuffer = kmalloc(sizeof(PAGE_SIZE), GFP_KERNEL);

bytesread = readfile(firstfile, firstbuffer, len, 0);

// Null terminate read string
firstbuffer[bytesread] = '\0';
printk("first buffer = %s\n",firstbuffer);
```

Then, I am calling this function again to read contents of secondfile into secondbuffer.

```
char *secondbuffer;
secondbuffer = kmalloc(sizeof(PAGE_SIZE), GFP_KERNEL);
bytesread2 = readfile(secondfile, secondbuffer, len, 0);
// Null terminate read string
secondbuffer[bytesread2] = '\0';
printk("second buffer %s", secondbuffer);
```

The problem is that after calling the read function on secondfile, the contents of my firstbuffer are getting overridden with contents of secondbuffer.

For example: if the contents of firstfile are

```
A
B
C
```

and contents of secondfile are

```
X
Y
Z
```

then after first read file call, the content of firstbuffer is:

```
A
B
C
```

and then after second read file call, the content of firstbuffer is:

```
A
X
Y
Z
```

Now, I am not sure what is going wrong here, but after second read function call, contents of firstbuffer is getting merged with contents of secondbuffer.  How do I fix this?

Disclaimer:

I know we shouldn't do file I/O in Kernel space. This is purely to learn how read functions work in Kernel space.

Comment: Can you print the value of `firstbuffer` and `secondbuffer`? E.g., `printf("1:%p\n2:%p\n", firstbuffer, secondbuffer);`

Comment: @jxh: Yes I am able to print their values. Using printk("%s\n,firstbuffer) and printk("%s\n,secondbuffer) to do so

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Done. added mcv example.

Comment: @Piyush What are the values?

Comment: ABC (before second call to read) and AXYZ (after second call to read) as mentioned in the answer. Secondbuffer's output is XYZ as expected. However, if I were to call read function again with first input file and first buffer, then  value of second buffer also gets merged with the 1st one while the output of 1st becomes ABC.

Comment: `%p` means I am interested in the value of the pointer itself, not the contents which you had already described in your post.

Comment: @jxh: Ahh sorry about that. first buffer = ffff88007a5b57e8 and secondbuffer = ffff88007a5b57f0. The value of first buffer's pointer doesn't change after second read call.

Comment: What are the values of `PAGE_SIZE` and `len`?

Comment: @immibis: I had declared len = Page_size and page_size should be 4096 as defined in the limits.h file. The issue was with memory allocation as you correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kmalloc(sizeof(PAGE_SIZE), GFP_KERNEL)
```

This allocates `sizeof(PAGE_SIZE)` bytes. Now, `PAGE_SIZE` is an integer, so it's probably 4 bytes long, so you allocate 4 bytes.

If you wanted to allocate `PAGE_SIZE` bytes, use:

```
kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL)
```

Comment: Ahh thank you so much. This solved the issue. What a stupid mistake. Now, I am not even sure how the program was working at all. I am sure I was writing more than 4 bytes to it all the time. Anyways, thank you again @immibis

Comment: @Piyush Allocating 4 bytes means the 4 bytes are reserved for you, but it doesn't mean only 4 bytes exist. You can write after the 4 bytes reserved to you and then you're writing over someone else's memory, or unused memory.